# Why does Function's prototype key seem to point towards a function and not an object like Object's prototype key

Tags: javascript

If you look at `Object` in Chrome DevTools you'll see that it's `prototype` property points towards an object, and I expect this.
[Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Tzv.png)

`Function`s `prototype` property looks like it points towards a function which I find suprising.
[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4tj7.png)

First of all, is this true? And if so, is there any reason why `Function`'s `prototype` key points towards a function object instead of just a plain object? (Are there any big implications to this?)

Comment: It has always been that way; it doesn't really have much of an effect on anything. A function object *is* an object, after all.

Comment: It does point towards an object, the keys are just functions. Functions in js are function-object combos

Comment: @RohitKashyap the question is about why `Function.prototype` is itself a built-in function object instead of a plain object.

Comment: @Pointy okay, good to know

Comment: @Pointy you literally just wrote the same thing that I did

Comment: @RohitKashyap perhaps I misunderstood your comment, in particular the phrase "the keys are just functions". The Function constructor is unusual among the built-in objects in that its prototype object is itself a function. All other prototypes of built-in objects are plain objects.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript follows Prototypal-Inheritance. And `Object` and `Function` are nothing but Constructor Functions. Any subsequent function or object created will hence inherit properties from the `prototype` (*).

With this pattern, it is obvious that a `prototype` of an `Object` points to an object and that of a function points to a function. It may be a bit confusing, hence it is recommended to follow [this](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-instances-prototype)

> "The Function prototype object is specified to be a function object to
> ensure compatibility with the ECMAScript code that was created prior
> to the ECMAScript 2015 specification."

(*) Be noted that functions are objects (you can add properties to them) in Javascript.